# Htaccess redirect from index.php to non-index

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to make a redirect to my htaccess with the follow:

```
http://example.com/index.php -> http://example.com
http://example.com/index.php/controller -> http://example.com/controller
http://example.com/index.php/controller/any-method -> http://example.com/controller/any-method
```

In 2 words, i want to detect if the URL contains index.php and redirect it to a url without it but to keep other segments after the index.php

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I'm looking for something simular. The solution redirects to a path via the file root not not the web root for me.